# Dialog Box loses focus in Windows XP

Tags: c#, focus, modal-dialog

I am having a strange problem. I have a C# .NET 2.0 application and a context menu. When you right click on the application, the context menu shows up and one of the items on the menu is Options. When you click options, I have an OptionsDialog form that shows up (using ShowDialog() method). The problem is, on Windows XP, the focus keeps going away. If I click on the options form, its gains focus for a second, but then loses it again! I have tried everything. On the Deactivate event, I call this.Focus() but that doesn't seem to make a difference. I also tried making the window topmost, but still doesn't work.

Another wierd thing is that this problem only seems to happen on XP. I tried it with Vista and Windows 7 and it works perfect. XP is doing something wierd though. Anyone have any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried on a different XP machine?

Comment: Yes. I use VMWare for testing my applications. I have to 2 seperate XP images that I use for testing and both do the same wierd behavior.

Comment: Have you tried using Spy++ to see the windows messages? You should be able to find what thread is pulling focus

Comment: I used Spy++ and I see its my own application is pulling the thread. I don't get how its happening though.

Comment: Where is this context menu invoked? My guess is that you're not specifying an owner window when you call ShowDialog(owner) and the arbitrary window chosen by default as owner is moving in z-order. Do you have a visible form that you can specify as the owner window?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it both ways. I originally just had ShowDialog() then changed it to ShowDialog(this). Same issue though

Comment: @icemanind: Are you still having this problem? Are you able to create a simple example app that demonstrates the behavior?

Comment: @Tergiver: I am still having this issue. Do you have an email address and I can just email you the source code and you can see for yourself. Like I said in the post, the problem only seems to show up in Windows XP. Works fine in Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: @icemanind: First I would advise you to start stripping parts of the application away until you end up with the simplest program that reproduces the behavior. This process can often be enough to expose the source of the problem. If it's not, it at least makes debugging a lot easier, especially if you're asking a 3rd party to look at it. If you hand it all off to me and the problem doesn't manifest itself readily, that's what I will have to do. It makes more sense for you to do the work. It's your application.. your problem. My email address is my name at msn dot com.

Answer (score 1):

A person here seems to have the same problem: http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/c-form-won-t-focus-on-control-535596.html

Is that anything like what's going wrong with you? If you have a default button or a control that is the first tabStop value that also happens to be disabled when the form starts up, it could be the cause of the problem.

Check any disabled controls on the form, and make sure the default button and the first tab stop controls are both enabled. (Hint: Default button should usually be 'Cancel' on a modal form, and it should always be enabled.)

Comment: The difference between my problem and that guy's problem, is it seems he is losing focus off a specific control. My problem is my WHOLE form loses control

Comment: You're right. Hmm, have you tried assigning the dialog result to a dummy variable when you call ShowDialog to see if it changes anything?

Comment: Yeah I am doing that anyway because I need to save the value of the DialogResult

Comment: This sounds like the behaviour of an offscreen modal dialog box opening on top of yours. When your dialog loses focus, does hitting return or escape have any effect? (such as restoring focus to your dialog momentarily)

Comment: No it doesn't have any effect. But I can tell you, other then my MainForm, my options dialog is the only other form in my project.

Comment: I don't doubt it - I was toying with the idea that maybe an error message was popping up off-screen and taking focus away from your dialog. Just a shot in the dark though. I'm pretty much out of ideas without playing with the app though. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you find out which window has the focus afterwards, maybe it gives you a clue what's going on.

This little demo app from 1997 will help you: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0397/Win32/Win320397.aspx